How to resize PDF pages to `Letter` using `pypdf`?
I noticed that the pypdf doesn't have a PaperSize of Letter (it only has A0-A8 & C4). I have PDF's of various page sizes that I want to standardize and scale to Letter size.
Is this possible with pypdf?

This question is similar to: PyPDF2 paper size manipulation. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Currently the Page sizes are only international (ISO) sizes.
But it is simple to add any custom size such as USA Letter.
Locate your copy of the following file https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/blob/main/pypdf/papersizes.py#L11
Add your preference after A8 so for example,
    A8 = Dimensions(147, 210)
    Letter = Dimensions(612, 792)

Then save the file and test if it works?
